# making a makefile error 'cc1plus' :execvp:no such file or directory

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile

how can i solve this problem :
cc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
make: *** [sum.o] Error 1
??
does it need to install any directories for c++ programming language or it is a matter of the way i wrote the code and divide it ! I'm using #ubuntu

Comment: It seems that your C++ compiler is not installed properly.

Comment: You may need to install a compiler or you may just need to update your search path or you may need to change the makefile to use an existing compiler. My crystal balls are in the shop so it's hard to say.

Comment: so do i suppose to install anything for now ?

Comment: Did you `apt-get install g++`?

Comment: no I didn't ! should I install it ?

Comment: Well, if you want to compile C++ code it's generally considered a prerequisite to install a C++ compiler... :-p